# em.merge performance issue in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity having oneToone mapping with other entity. 
Example

```
EntityA
{
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private EntityB user;

}
```

Now when I try to update the EntityA using em.merge(entity),

in the background instead of directly firing the update query , hibernate fires some select query on
EntityA object and then on EntityB object and then when flush is called , update query is fired.
Basically whole existing object of EntityA inclusive of EntityB (which exist in DB) is created. and then i beleive this object is updated which is then saved.

There is lot of performance issue when the relation is oneToMany .Is there something in JPA where when I want to update only EntityA , EntityB is not fetched from DB and I directly update EntityA

Comment: You using CascadeType.DETACH.. remove it in order to does not perform any update

Comment: Wont it impact the EntityA association with EntityB. Could I still be able to access EntityB object using EntityA